# How do I parse this JSON string?

Tags: android, android-json

I am working on app in which I have to parse below JSON.

Anyone can anyone tell me how to do this?

```
{
    "navigation_entries": {
        "home": {
            "children": [
                "favorites",
                "calendar",
                "offers",
                "wineries",
                "dining",
                "lodging",
                "things_to_do",
                "weather",
                "settings"
            ],
            "banner_image": "home_page_banner",
            "icon": {
                "small": "icon_home_small",
                "large": "icon_home_large"
            },
            "type": "home_page",
            "forward_icon": {
                "small": "icon_right_arrow_small",
                "large": "icon_right_arrow_large"
            },
            "link_name": "Home"
        },
        "wineries": {
            "display_name": "Wineries",
            "icon": {
                "small": "icon_wineries_small",
                "large": "icon_wineries_large"
            },
            "line_template": "wineries_list_template",
            "forward_icon": {
                "small": "icon_right_arrow_small",
                "large": "icon_right_arrow_large"
            },
            "link_name": "Wineries",
            "type": "leaf_list",
            "leaf_template": "wineries_leaf_template",
            "section": "wineries"
        },
        "dining": {
            "display_name": "Dining",
            "icon": {
                "small": "icon_dining_small",
                "large": "icon_dining_large"
            },
            "line_template": "dining_list_template",
            "forward_icon": {
                "small": "icon_right_arrow_small",
                "large": "icon_right_arrow_large"
            },
            "link_name": "Dining",
            "type": "leaf_list",
            "leaf_template": "dining_leaf_template",
            "section": "dining"
        },
        "offers_dining": {
            "display_name": "Offers => Dining",
            "list_name": "Dining",
            "line_template": "offers_dining_list_template",
            "type": "leaf_list",
            "leaf_template": "offers_dining_leaf_template",
            "forward_icon": {
                "small": "icon_right_arrow_small",
                "large": "icon_right_arrow_large"
            },
            "section": "offers_dining"
        },
        "favorites": {
            "display_name": "Favorites",
            "icon": {
                "small": "icon_favorites_small",
                "large": "icon_favorites_large"
            },
            "type": "favorites",
            "forward_icon": {
                "small": "icon_right_arrow_small",
                "large": "icon_right_arrow_large"
            },
            "link_name": "Favorites"
        },
        "offers": {
            "display_name": "Offers",
            "children": [
                "offers_wineries",
                "offers_dining",
                "offers_lodging",
                "offers_things_to_do"
            ],
            "icon": {
                "small": "icon_offers_small",
                "large": "icon_offers_large"
            },
            "type": "navigation_list",
            "forward_icon": {
                "small": "icon_right_arrow_small",
                "large": "icon_right_arrow_large"
            },
            "link_name": "Offers"
        }
    },
    "type": "navigation"
}
```

Comment: Good formatting is your friend.

Comment: The Json string above provided is not a valid one. Can u pls provide the correct Json string. You can make use of the following link to check its validity: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: The JSON string above is not valid beacause there is the lable "show" at the beginning of it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse json string in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091051/how-to-parse-json-string-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [this website](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) to format your JSON string in a in an easier way to view it.
Android provides an appropiate library to do what you want.

[This](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html) is the manual page you need to comprehend how to use Android JSON API.

And [here](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/10/json-parsing-in-android/) you can see a tutorial to understand how to parse JSON string.

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the example above is your string, you can parse it passing it to the JSONObject constructor:

```
String jsonString = "...."; // the above string
try {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // This exception is thrown if jsonString is not correctly formatted
}
```

Now, if you want to get the JSONObject labled "GlossList", inside the string above, you can do this:

```
JSONObject glossList = obj.getJSONObject("glossary").getJSONObject("GlossDiv").getJSONObject("GlossList");
```

There is also another possibility: you can also obtain some JSONArray. In our example, the array GlossSeeAlso:

```
JSONArray glossSee = glossList.getJSONObject("GlossEntry").getJSONObject("GlossDef").getJSONArray("GlossSeeAlso");
```

To get directly a value of this array, you can use the method `getString(int i)`; if the contend of the array is a JSONObject, you can use the method `getJSONObject(int i)`. You can also use the method `getString(String lable)` to get directly a string in a JSONObject:

```
String title = glossDive.getString("title");
String firstElement = glossSee.getString(0);
```

Other examples are available in the [official JSON site](http://json.org/example.html).

Comment: Vito Shadow , Can you please tell me how to use google charts AND fussion charts in android . Please tell me how to use both .Your help will be appreciated

Comment: Please, if you like this answer, can you accept my answer?
I've never used Google and fussion charts... Sorry, I cannot help you... Try open another question, someone will help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) and [JSONTokener](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html) like this:

```
String json = "{"
     + "  \"query\": \"Pizza\", "
     + "  \"locations\": [ 94043, 90210 ] "
     + "}";

JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(json).nextValue();
String query = object.getString("query");
JSONArray locations = object.getJSONArray("locations");
```

Answer (score 0):

jsonlint.com has a very good json formatter. this should make your text easily understandable.

for parsing this data, you can use JSONObject (org.json.JSONObject)