# How to load json file into kotlin module to be parsed by GSON

Tags: android, json, gson, inputstream

I need to read a Json file to load data into memory.

The project has the following structure of modules:

```
|_ app
|_ data
   |_ datasource
   |_ theory.json       
|_ domain
```

I tried to save the json file into `data` module, and then in the datasource class I tried to read the file to be parsed by GSON library.

So I tried into a Kotlin class of the `data` module:

```
val fileInputStream = FileInputStream("theory.json")
val fileInputStream = FileInputStream("/theory.json")
val fileInputStream = FileInputStream("../theory.json")
```

And always I'm getting the this error:

```
theory.json: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

But I put the file in the `assets` folder  of package `app`, and then I do:

```
|_ app
   |_assets
     |_ theory.json      
|_ data
   |_ datasource 
|_ domain

val file = context?.assets?.open("theory.json")
```

Once I get the file I'm able to read the file and parse it with the Gson Library, so it works perfect.

The problem here is that to make the datasource work , I need to create the file into de `app` module, then start to pass it via params to datasource.

Is there any way to make it work "isolated" from the `app` module, and make it work in the `data` module?

Comment: I don't think it's possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27441831/android-accessing-assets-form-library-project/27636288

Comment: Actually try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/22254488/1419353

Comment: Thanks, I'll take look to the second link to see if I can do something. If not, I'll leave it as I have now.
Thanks!

Comment: before answering in can you tell me what kind of project is this? Because on a project to project basis we have a different structures to store data to be easily read from.

Comment: @Shudy Did you find any solution for it?