# Android-JSON Parsing

Tags: android, json, android-layout, android-intent

I have a JSON string like this:

```
["<a href='http://adda.com/jsonFeed/faJsonFeedDetails.php?jid=12036'>SPICE JET Recruits Freshers Data Entry Operator in Gurgaon</a><br><br><br>","<a href='http://adda.com/jsonFeed/faJsonFeedDetails.php?jid=12035'>TOSHIBA Freshers off Campus Drive Trainee Engineers in Bangalore </a><br><br><br>","<a href='http://adda.com/jsonFeed/faJsonFeedDetails.php?jid=12034'>EMC Corporation Recruits Fresher Jobs Technical Support Engineers in bangalore</a><br><br><br>"]
```

I want to parse the `href` value and `title` from the above JSON string. Can any one help?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: I know about XML Parsing in Andriod ,but dont know jsonParsing

Comment: As you don't know JSON Parsing, here is [JSON Parsing tutorial/example](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-json-parsing/). Try to read, understand and implement by your own.

Comment: you can try this [also](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

Comment: @String, isn't my answer helped you? 3 up votes there, mark accept if helpful so other googler get benefits from it. :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay,It got helped me,I accepted, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following code.

```
try {
    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(json);
    int size = ja.length();
    Log.d("tag","No of Elements " + ja.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        String str = ja.getString(i);
        String href = str.substring(str.indexOf("href=") + 5,
                str.indexOf(">"));
        Log.d("tag",href);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In this code, **json** will be your string, like

```
String json = "[\"<a href='http://adda.com/jsonFeed/faJsonFeedDetails.php?jid=12036'>SPICE JET Recruits Freshers Data Entry Operator in Gurgaon</a><br><br><br>\",\"<a href='http://adda.com/jsonFeed/faJsonFeedDetails.php?jid=12035'>TOSHIBA Freshers off Campus Drive Trainee Engineers in Bangalore </a><br><br><br>\",\"<a href='http://adda.com/jsonFeed/faJsonFeedDetails.php?jid=12034'>EMC Corporation Recruits Fresher Jobs Technical Support Engineers in bangalore</a><br><br><br>\"]";
```

Output will be like following.

```
06-04 16:50:44.632: tag : 'http://adda.com/jsonFeed/faJsonFeedDetails.php?jid=12036'
06-04 16:50:44.632: tag : 'http://adda.com/jsonFeed/faJsonFeedDetails.php?jid=12035'
06-04 16:50:44.632: tag : 'http://adda.com/jsonFeed/faJsonFeedDetails.php?jid=12034'
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this [topic](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html) in Android official documentation, and check the following SO answers too:

- [How to parse JSON in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)
- [How to parse json string in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091051/how-to-parse-json-string-in-android)
- [JSON Array iteration in Android/Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408985/json-array-iteration-in-android-java)

And [here](https://github.com/barriosnahuel/tourGuide/blob/master/src/main/java/org/nbempire/android/tourguide/dao/impl/WikipediaDaoImplSpring.java) you've got a working example of retrieving a JSON array using [Spring for Android](http://www.springsource.org/spring-android) (by consuming a REST service).

Answer (score 0):

It is easy.Get JSONObjects from JSONArray and then parse each JSONObject separately.You can see [Android JSON Parsing Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) for more details.