# Read data from JSON Array android

Tags: android, json

When send email parameters to server and the response is shown  as a string below.

```
[
{
    "nid": "478",
    "field_mc_bacheliers_value": "0",
    "field_mc_defi_collectif_value": "1"
},
{
    "nid": "480",
    "field_mc_bacheliers_value": "0",
    "field_mc_defi_collectif_value": "1"    
}
]
```

I want to read this response String format into jsonobject. I it is the first time i work with json.

Comment: Use JsonArray class. which Parses the json and Create array of JSON Object

Comment: is it valid json . check here http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Use [new JSONObject(string)](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#JSONObject%28java.lang.String%29)...

Comment: @devconsole the string is a JSONArray

Comment: @blackbelt you are right, it is [new JSONArray(string)](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#JSONArray%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 5):

Considering the below extra curly brace removed `}`

```
[
{
    "nid": "478",
    "field_mc_bacheliers_value": "0",
    "field_mc_defi_collectif_value": "1"
},
{
    "nid": "480",
    "field_mc_bacheliers_value": "0",
    "field_mc_defi_collectif_value": "1"
}
]
```

To parse

```
  JSONArray myListsAll= new JSONArray(myjsonstring);
  for(int i=0;i<myListsAll.length();i++){
  JSONObject jsonobject= (JSONObject) myListsAll.get(i);
  String id=jsonobject.optString("nid");
  String value1=jsonobject.optString("field_mc_bacheliers_value");
  String value2=jsonobject.optString("field_mc_defi_collectif_value");  
  System.out.println("nid="+id);
  System.out.println("value1="+value1);
  System.out.println("value2="+value2); 
  }
```

Output

```
nid=478
value1=0
value2=1
nid=480
value1=0
value2=1
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove this extra curly braces '}'

You can refer below code For the json

```
[ 
{
  "name" : "Test",
  "id" : 512
}, {
  "name" : "Test2",
  "id" : 573
}, {
  "name" : "Test3",
  "id" : 585
}
]
```

Parse Like this

```
ArrayList<String> arrProducts = new ArrayList<String>();

try {
    JSONArray valarray = new JSONArray(jsonstring);
    for (int i = 0; i < valarray.length(); i++) {

        String str = valarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
        arrProducts.add(str);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("JSON", "There was an error parsing the JSON", e);
}
```

Comment: what if i have to add id field too i need setter and getter method ?

Comment: Yes you need to create methods. You can refer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16938507/1441666

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
jString=[{"nid":"478","field_mc_bacheliers_value":"0","field_mc_defi_collectif_value":"1"},{"nid":"480","field_mc_bacheliers_value":"0","field_mc_defi_collectif_value":"1"}}]
    jObject = new JSONObject(jString);
   String id = jObject .getString("id");
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

It is not valid JSON, you have an extra } at the end.

```
[
  {
    "nid": "478",
    "field_mc_bacheliers_value": "0",
    "field_mc_defi_collectif_value": "1"
  },
  {
    "nid": "480",
    "field_mc_bacheliers_value": "0",
    "field_mc_defi_collectif_value": "1"
  }
} <-- this is invalid
]
```

You can check that here: http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

This question has more hints for JSON parsing: [How to parse JSON in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: this is an example of json format i want to convert it to JSNOBject to get the values inside

Comment: Cool, nice the online JSON checker!