# Getting json from json array starting from array

Tags: android, json

[ {"serviceData": [ {"id": "1","service_name": "Plumber","act_stat": "1"},]}]
how to get this json Structure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON Array (Not Json Object) in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977144/how-to-parse-json-array-not-json-object-in-android)

Comment: See the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/53507481/3145960

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String jsonString;
JSONArray jsonArray= new JSONArray(jsonString;);
for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
{
JSONObject jsono= (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
JSONArray ServiceArray= (JSONArray ) jsono.get(i);
 for(int j=0;j<ServiceArray.length();j++)
 {
 String id=jsonobject.getString("id");
 String service_name=jsonobject.getString("service_name");
 String act_stat=jsonobject.getString("act_stat");
 }
}
```

You can refer this post :  [How to Parse the JSON String Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938177/how-to-parse-the-json-string-android/16938507#16938507) for more details

Comment: `serviceData ` is also an array

Answer (score 0):

> First of all get **JSONObject** from **JSONArray** and then get particular field from that **JSONObject** like below :

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
SONArray jArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("serviceData");
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = jObject.getString("id");
            String service_name = jObject.getString("service_name");
            String act_stat = jObject.getString("act_stat");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> First of all get **JSONObject** from **JSONArray** and then get particular field from that **JSONObject** like below :

```
JSONArray array;
for(int n = 0; n < array.length(); n++)
{
JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(n);
String id = object .getString("id");
String service_name = object .getString("service_name");
String act_stat = object .getString("act_stat");
}
```