# How to parse a JSON string in android

Tags: android, json, parsing

My web  service outputs a `JSON` string that I need to parse.

Could you please tell me how i can parse the given `JSON` string:

```
{
"access_token":"kfwsfdcscfnsdcfsdsdfsd6f7df9sd6f89sd6s",
 "expires_in":3600,
 "token_type":"bearer",
 "scope":null,
 "refresh_token":"5dfddf1d6dfd1fddgdgdg1dg56d1"
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(Your_Sring_data);
  JSONObject uniObject = mainObject.getJSONObject("university");
  String  uniName = uniObject.getJSONObject("name");
  String uniURL = uniObject.getJSONObject("url");

  JSONObject oneObject = mainObject.getJSONObject("1");
  String id = oneObject.getJSONObject("id");
```

**refer this link:**

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091051/how-to-parse-json-string-in-android
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String jsonString = ""; //This'll contain the jsonString you mentioned above. 

JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonString);
String accessToken = object.getString("access_token");
```

Similarly fetch other values.

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{  // represents json object node
"access_token":"kfwsfdcscfnsdcfsdsdfsd6f7df9sd6f89sd6s", // key value pair
```

To parse

```
 JSONObject jb = new JSONObject("jsonstring");
 String acess_token = jb.getString("acess_token"); // acess_token is the key
 // similarly others
```

You can also use Gson to convert json string to java object.

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Using Gson

Download the jar add to the projects libs folder

Then

```
public class Response {

    String acess_token,expires_in,token_typerefresh_token;
}
```

Then

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader (is);
Gson gson = new Gson();         
Response lis = new Gson().fromJson(isr, Response.class);
Log.i("Acess Toekn is ",""+lis.expires_in);
```