# JSON returning empty array. Android

Tags: android, arrays, json, parsing, post

The following is my code. It is returning empty array, like: Array
                                                            (
                                                            ) 
Please check my code below and let me know what change is to be made. I am creating an JSON array and want to post it to an url.

```
                 String checkin = edit_message.getText().toString();
                 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                 String httppostURL = "http:// ...";
                 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(httppostURL);
                 Log.v(TAG, "postURL: " + httppost);   

                       JSONObject data1 = new JSONObject();
                       data1.put("merchant_id", "02");
                       data1.put("merchant_location_id", "03");
                       data1.put("user_id", "04");
                       data1.put("merchant_kiosk_id", "04");
                       data1.put("subscriber_phone", checkin);

                       JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                       jsonArray.put(data1);

                       JSONObject data= new JSONObject();
                       data.put("data",jsonArray); 

                        httppost.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
                        //httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data , "UTF-8"));
                        StringEntity se= new StringEntity(data.toString());
                        se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json"));
                        httppost.setEntity(se);                 
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();  
                        if (resEntity != null) {                               
                            String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();
                            Log.v(TAG, "Response: " +  responseStr);
                            Log.i("TAG",""+response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                            Toast.makeText(CheckinActivity.this,  responseStr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                            //you can add an if statement here and do other actions based on the response
                        }               
                        edit_message.setText("");
                        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Toast.makeText(CheckinActivity.this, "Data: " +data,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                 } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 } catch (Throwable t) {
                     Toast.makeText(CheckinActivity.this, "Request failed: " + t.toString(),
                             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }

            }

    }
```

UPDATE:

Instead of

```
JSONObject data= new JSONObject();                         
data.put("data",jsonArray);
```

I used:

```
List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", data1.toString()));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));
```

UPDATE 2

I have a json response like this

```
{"msg":Successfully logged in,"status":1}
```

If status = 1, I want to do some activity & if status = 0, I want to do something else. How to achieve this? And where to put the code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: if getting `Array ( )` in response means problem is in api on server side

Comment: List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
                         nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", data.toString()));
                         httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));

Comment: I have a json response like this

{"msg":Successfully logged in,"status":1}
If status = 1, I want to do some activity & if status = 0, I want to do something else. How to achieve this? And where to put the code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JSON classes for parsing e.g
You can use below code for parsing.

```
JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(responseStr);
int status = mainObject.getInt("status");
if(status==1){
    //do something
}else{
    //do something else
}
....
```

Is this what you want?? please update the question title to get what exactly you need.

Comment: Also, this will be helpful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091051/how-to-parse-json-string-in-android

Answer (score 0):

```
   String checkin = edit_message.getText().toString();
                 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                 String httppostURL = "http://192.168.0.254/nepadeals/androidweb/checkin";
                 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(httppostURL);
                 Log.v(TAG, "postURL: " + httppost);   

                       JSONObject data1 = new JSONObject();
                       data1.put("merchant_id", "02");
                       data1.put("merchant_location_id", "03");
                       data1.put("user_id", "04");
                       data1.put("merchant_kiosk_id", "04");
                       data1.put("subscriber_phone", checkin);

                       JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                       jsonArray.put(data1);

                       JSONObject data= new JSONObject();
                       data.put("data",jsonArray); 

                        httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json;" + HTTP.UTF_8);
                        StringEntity se= new StringEntity(data.toString(),HTTP.UTF_8);

                        httppost.setEntity(se);                 
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();  
                        if (resEntity != null) {                               
                            String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();
                            Log.v(TAG, "Response: " +  responseStr);
                            Log.i("TAG",""+response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                            Toast.makeText(CheckinActivity.this,  responseStr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                            //you can add an if statement here and do other actions based on the response
                        }               
                        edit_message.setText("");
                        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Toast.makeText(CheckinActivity.this, "Data: " +data,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                 } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 } catch (Throwable t) {
                     Toast.makeText(CheckinActivity.this, "Request failed: " + t.toString(),
                             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }

            }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks. But it didn't work. I did: List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
                         nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", data.toString()));
                         httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));

Comment: I have a json response like this

{"msg":Successfully logged in,"status":1}
If status = 1, I want to do some activity & if status = 0, I want to do something else. How to achieve this? And where to put the code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
String checkin = edit_message.getText().toString();
                 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                 String httppostURL = "http://192.168.0.254/nepadeals/androidweb/checkin";
                 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(httppostURL);
                 Log.v(TAG, "postURL: " + httppost);   

                       JSONObject data1 = new JSONObject();
                       data1.put("merchant_id", "02");
                       data1.put("merchant_location_id", "03");
                       data1.put("user_id", "04");
                       data1.put("merchant_kiosk_id", "04");
                       data1.put("subscriber_phone", checkin);

                       JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                       jsonArray.put(data1);

                       JSONObject data= new JSONObject();
                       data.put("data",jsonArray); 

                        httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json;" + HTTP.UTF_8);
                        StringEntity se= new StringEntity(data.toString(),HTTP.UTF_8);

                        httppost.setEntity(se);                 
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(content, HTTP.UTF_8));
                String line;
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }

                result = builder.toString();

                 } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 } catch (Throwable t) {
                     Toast.makeText(CheckinActivity.this, "Request failed: " + t.toString(),
                             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }

            }
protected void onPostExecute(Void data) {
        super.onPostExecute(data);
JSONObject object1 = new JSONObject(result);        
String status=object1.getString("status");
int value=0;
if(status!=null)
{
value=Integer.parseInt(status);
}
if(value==1)
{
//do some task
}
else
{
//do some task
}
}
    }
```