# how to parse this json formate using Gson lib

Tags: android

> how to parse sub array like as getString("sub") using gson lib in android.

```
<pre>
{
   "name"  : "abc";
  "class" : "xyz";
   "address" : {[
             "add" : "1";
             "sub" :["abc"];
          ]}
     }
  </pre>
```

Comment: This is an invalid json schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should reduce your JSON to correct form:

```
{
   "name"  : "abc",
   "class" : "xyz",
   "address" : [
         {"add" : "1",
         "sub" :["abc"]}
      ]
}
```

Now, create objects with following structure:

```
class Foo{
   String name;
   String class;
   Address[] address;
}

class Address{
   String add;
   String[] sub; 
}
```

And on this step you can easily parse JSON to an object, by calling this line:

```
Foo foo = new Gson().fromJson(json, Foo.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is invalid JSON, some combination of XML and JSON.
This is the way how to parse JSON in Android [How to parse json string in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091051/how-to-parse-json-string-in-android) 
And this is JSON schema wiki post https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON