# Get dirrectly data in Json with Gson

Tags: android, json, parsing, gson

I have a json string same:

```
{
   k1: v1,
   k2: v2,
   k3: {
     k31:{
        k32:{
          k33:{
             k34: v3
          }
        }
     }
   }
   k4: v4,
   k5: v5,
   k6: v6,
}
```

I create a object Object `K = {k1, k2, k3, k4, k5, k6}` and value get from abover string should be `{v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6}`

With Gson it is easy to get `v1, v2, v4, v5, v6.`
With **v3**, How to get it directly, I don't want make a object wrapper `k33`, then `k32`, then `k31`, then `k3` to get v3.

We also can't pass `k31, k32, k33, k34` to get `v3` as Jsoup
if @SerializedName struct as @SerializedName("k3.k31.k32.k33.k34").

Pls show me a solution for this case.

Comment: i think you must traverse to get the object.You can't get the v3 directly.Only XML have such a functionality.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse json string in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091051/how-to-parse-json-string-in-android)

Comment: Sorry, I need a solution with Gson to dirrectly parse, not how to parse generally.

Comment: If is easy if Gson have @SerializedName struct as @SerializedName("k3.k31.k32.k33.k34"). But it has not

Comment: study this and do some code so we can help you: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

Comment: @SuhasB Please read my question clearer. I'm not started with Gson. Here, I want get v3 dirrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Gson, ou can treat k3, and k31 through k34 as Json Arrays. K34 is then a Json Object to get the value for k34. Try this:

```
String  value = jsonObj.getAsJsonArray("k3").getAsJsonArray("k31")
.getAsJsonArray("k32").getAsJsonArray("k33").getAsJsonObject().get("k34");
```